# How to mock function in C when its caller function is defined in same file?

Tags: c, linux, c++11, gcc, cmocka

I am trying to mock a function in C, mocking works fine when the function and its caller function are defined in different files. But when both functions (function itself and its caller) are defined in the same file, the mocked function does not get invoked.

---

Case 1 :

```
//test.c

#include <stdio.h>

/*mocked function*/
int __wrap_func() {
   printf("Mock function !!!\n"); 
}

/*caller function*/
int myTest() {
  return func();
}

int main() {
    myTest();
    return 0;
}

//file.c
#include<stdio.h>

/*function need to be mocked*/
int func() {
  printf("Original function !!!\n");
    }
```

---

Case 2 :

```
//test.c
#include <stdio.h>
extern int myTest();
/*mocked function*/
int __wrap_func() {
  printf("Mock function !!!\n");
}

int main() {
    myTest();
}
//file.c
#include<stdio.h>

/*function need to be mocked*/
int func() {
  printf("Original function !!!\n");
}

/*caller function*/
int myTest() {
  return func();
}
```

---

Code compilation command : gcc -Wl,--wrap=func test.c file.c

```
In Case 1 . Mock function !!!
In Case 2 . Original function !!!
```

In case 2, mocking function is not being invoked. I am looking for a solution  where I can mock function even caller and called function are in same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.

From [the linker documentation](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html),

> --wrap symbol
>       Use a wrapper function for symbol. Any undefined reference to symbol will be resolved to __wrap_symbol. Any undefined reference to
>   __real_symbol will be resolved to symbol. This can be used to provide a wrapper for a system function. The wrapper function should be called
>   __wrap_symbol. If it wishes to call the system function, it should call __real_symbol. Here is a trivial example:
>
> ```
> void *
> __wrap_malloc (int c)
> {
>   printf ("malloc called with %ld\n", c);
>   return __real_malloc (c);
> }
> ```
>
> If you link other code with this file using --wrap malloc, then all calls to malloc will call the function __wrap_malloc instead. The
>   call to __real_malloc in __wrap_malloc will call the real malloc
>   function. You may wish to provide a __real_malloc function as well, so
>   that links without the --wrap option will succeed.

Here'e the iimportant part ...

> If you do this, you
>   should not put the definition of __real_malloc in the same file as
>   __wrap_malloc; if you do, the assembler may resolve the call before the linker has a chance to wrap it to malloc.

Answer (score 3):

Using a function name starting with two underscores is *undefined behaviour* in C.

(In your case I suspect that the function name `__wrap_func` is clashing with the *decorated* name for `func` but that's speculative and entirely compiler-dependent.)

You ought to consider a solution using *function pointers* instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using `--wrap=symbol` linker option will result so that undefined symbols will be resolved as `__wrap_symbol`. 
In your first case, `func` is undefined symbol so linker will search for `__wrap_func` and that function is called.
In your second case, linker finds `myTest` because it is declared `extern`.
When `myTest` calls `func` it is in the same translation unit so not undefiend that resides in the same file as being `int func()`. So the original `func` is calles instead of wrapped version. Your design is not suitable for using mocked functions when caller and callee are in the same file as well as in different files.
I suggest you to use `MACRO` or `function pointer` technique as explained [here](http://locklessinc.com/articles/mocking/).